# If condition using CSS

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

It is possible to verify if a typescript variable is true using CSS ?
I'm trying to verify if I am in a specific page, then modify the height of the page.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just modify the height of the page from TypeScript directly? CSS variables are available in pre-processors such as SASS, though are unnecessary for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: it is a good point. But for example when I am in the second component I want to change the height of the third component, and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngStyle]="{expression: value}"